# how to ensure java compareTo resturn same result as Database ORDER BY?

Tags: java, database

In unit tests I verify the result from a Db query that contains an "ORDER BY DESC" part and return String values.

To be clear: I check that the query returns the expected result in the expected order

SQL query:

```
SELECT member.name FROM member ORDER BY member.name DESC
```

**Test result:**

```
MTH_TESTER_TAXER_W_HLPERS_AFcCmhecUo
MTH_TESTER_TAXER_wCfRUAQuzT
```

When verifying the result with java, I do:

```
foreach(String value : values) {
  if (previous != null) {
   assertTrue(value.compareToIgnoreCase(previous) <= 0);
  }  
  previous = value;
}
```

Which fails using the above DB result from the ORDER BY (descending order in above example).
So basically the following in java fails but not in DB:

```
assertTrue("MTH_TESTER_TAXER_wCfRUAQuzT".compareToIgnoreCase("MTH_TESTER_TAXER_W_HLPERS_AFcCmhecUo") <= 0)
```

Why is the ORDER BY not compatible with the Java compareTo natural String ordering?

And how to make them compatible?

I use Postgresql 9.X on Windowsd 7, default installation.

Comment: You want to sort list of strings in descending order?

Comment: please post code that actually could compile

Comment: I suspect the sql order by is case-sensitive, but you haven't shown enough code.  And I doubt the java code you've shown is accurate, as there's a misplaced paren.

Comment: @Almas: I want to verify the result of the sql query that contains "ORDER BY DESC", so yes, it's descending order.

Comment: @Peter: sorry, I corrected the code.

Comment: @Don: I use compareToIgnoreCase so case-sensitive wouldn't make a difference I quess. I think its the character set being used, but not sure..

Comment: You use compareToIgnoreCase in Java, but you're saying it doesn't match your sql result.  What do you use in sql?

Comment: @Don: just updated the question with sql code, enough?

Comment: Yes.  That clarifies.  And I might post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Try using string's [CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER):

```
 String[] str = {"abc", "pqr", "zxt", "Zxy", "xyz"};
 Arrays.sort(str, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.reversed());
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
```

Comment: Thanks, but not solve the problem. Note: the String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER is also used by the String.compareToIgnoreCase() method.

Comment: But you are not writing comparator which will be used to sort the array or your collections. What's the issue now?

Comment: That the comparator that is used by String.compareToIgnoreCase() doesn't return the same result as the "ORDER BY member.name DESC" from postgresql db.

Comment: Can you give some example so i know what you are talking about?

Comment: what result you get from SQL and what you get by running Java sort and how they both are different?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. The SQL query is in the question (SELECT member.name FROM member ORDER BY member.name DESC) and the result also: the 2 names. And the difference is explained in the text.

Comment: Am not sure what exactly you after. But i see the same result as what you pasted. Am sorry i can't do more than this.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to get an answer to the original question: "why is the compareToIgnoreCase() not comptabile with the ORDER BY result of the DB query

Answer (score 0):

If you change your sql to

```
SELECT member.name FROM member ORDER BY UPPER(member.name) DESC
```

your Java code will likely verify this order.

Alternatively, if you change your Java code to

```
foreach(String value : values) {
  if (previous != null) {
   assertTrue(value.compareTo(previous) <= 0);
  }  
  previous = value;
}
```

it should verify the case-sensitive order being done by your current sql.

Comment: Thanks, but if I use you java code, my verification still fails (just added the actual compareTo that fails).

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions here:

1. You don't rely on `ORDER BY` at all. You can use it but before you compare, you sort the actual output again in Java to make sure the order is always the same.

   Use this approach if you only need to make sure that the actual sort order of the query doesn't really matter, only the number and content of the elements.
2. Instead of comparing each string individually, join the results into one multi-line string and then do a single `assertEquals()` with a constant string.

The second solution looks like this:

```
String actual = Joiner.on('\n').join(Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(values));
assertEquals(
     "MTH_TESTER_TAXER_W_HLPERS_AFcCmhecUo\n" +
     "MTH_TESTER_TAXER_wCfRUAQuzT",
     actual
);
```

The second test checks all values at once, allowing you to see with a single glance which values have changed, which are unexpected and which are missing.

It also allows you to safely test the ordering of results as returned by the database.

Comment: If you resort in the Java then there's no guarantee that your database query is correct

Comment: @MrWiggles: That's what the second strategy is for.

Comment: See my answer for the hamcrest version which doesn't require any string manipulation

Comment: I like the nice API of hamcrest but the IDE support for displaying the results sucks.

Comment: Really? I've never really had an issue with it.  AssertJ is another option but it feels a little bit too strict for me

Comment: Thanks, but the problems lies in the order of the query result which I verify in a unit test. I suppose your code still results in the same result as my compareToIgnoreCase() construction

Comment: @edbras: No, it doesn't. The first difference will abort your test and the rest of the results won't be tested. My code tests all results and their order in a single compare so you see all differences at once. Using `compareToIgnoreCase()` probably doesn't make sense since you shouldn't test the database code. The database vendors does that for you.

Comment: Thanks, But why is the outcome from compareToIgnoreCase not compatible with the ORDER BY DESC of the db (original question)? (I don't use Hamcrest btw)

Comment: The reason is called "collation" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation). How do you sort `a`, `A` and `ä`. Should they all be the same (folding)? Or is there an order which makes sense for some reason? Should the upper or lower case letters come first? Most systems compare by simply comparing the bytes (for one-byte encodings) or Unicode code point but for real-world applications, you need more flexibility. Check your DB's manuals to see how you can define the sort order of individual characters. For Java, see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to verify that your database query works correctly? If so, then i would first ensure I know *exactly* what is coming back from the database.  There's no information in your code, but I would hope you're seeding the data before the test runs either through direct SQL or something like dbUnit.

Once you have this then you can do an exact comparison on the returned results in the test.  I would avoid the test you currently have as it gives you no diagnostics about what is wrong when the test fails.  When you have this in place your test can be something like:

```
List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("MTH_TESTER_TAXER_W_HLPERS_AFcCmhecUo", "MTH_TESTER_TAXER_wCfRUAQuzT");
List<String> actual = myCode.performQuery(); // <-- your method under test goes here
assertThat(expected, contains(actual));
```

This will ensure the collection you return has the same items in the same order as you specify and if something differs it will tell you exactly what.

Comment: The DB query returns a sorted collected of items and in a unit test I verify the order of the items in the collection. Because the items are expected to be in natural descending order, I use compareToIgnoreCase(). I am not sure what content if the db is, and in this test case not needed, at least I know that a few hunderd members with names are present. Even if would insert my own test data before the test, I would use compareToIgnoreCase() to create my members...(used to create your test array)

Comment: If you know what the members are, why would you use `compareToIgnoreCase()`? If you're using a changing database instead of a clean setup at some point your tests are going to start failing due to a moving target

Comment: Because I want to verify the query result. A moving target is even desired in this case as it better matches the production/real situation.

Comment: Testing with a moving target really should be the focus of a different test.  It seems like this one is here to validate your logic functionally works as expected and so would be better off with a clean, deterministic data-set

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't answer my original question